# Convert from ipaddr to netaddr:cidr type

Tags: ruby, networking

Using ruby 2.0.0, how can I convert an object of type `IPAddr` to a `NetAddr::CIDR`?

Example:

```
IPAddr.new("1a03:a240:0100::/56")
IPAddr.new("192.1268.1.0/24")
```

This does not work, as I doesn't respect the netmask/ prefix:

```
NetAddr::CIDR.create(IPAddr.new("1a03:a240:0100::/56").to_s).to_s
=> "1a03:a240:0100:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000/128"
```

Comment: Why are you using both IPAddr and NetAddr? NetAddr has more functionality built into it than IPAddr does.

Comment: Rails 4 automatically uses IPAddr when you have database columns of type cidr or inet, which sucks.

Comment: You don't have to use it though. Grab the values and throw them into NetAddr. Also, in my work, which involves lots of IPs at times, we don't use either type natively. I store IPv4 and IPv6 as text, plus have text CIDR and network bitmasks stored for convenience. I convert on the fly and don't let the ORM tell me what to do; I'm the boss of it. I do IP manipulations in the database using big integer values, but again, don't let the ORM pick the datatypes for me.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I do now too, but I don't really like it. I prefer to have the db validate the data too. Also when doing calculations, I now always have to typecast like address::cidr....

Comment: What DBM are you using? MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another solution we use at [Discourse](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/0398ab7514114154cd5b6c0782f80f1ff8523990/lib/ip_addr.rb)

```
class IPAddr

  def to_cidr_s
    if @addr
      mask = @mask_addr.to_s(2).count('1')
      "#{to_s}/#{mask}"
    else
      nil
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to extend the current `IPAddr`class (at least on 2.0.0). As ruby allows to extend classes by simply re-opening it, you'll have access to all required instance variables you need to calculate the prefix and display it.

```
class IPAddr
  def prefix
    begin_addr = (@addr & @mask_addr)

    case @family
      when Socket::AF_INET
        end_addr = (@addr | (IN4MASK ^ @mask_addr))
      when Socket::AF_INET6
        end_addr = (@addr | (IN6MASK ^ @mask_addr))
      end

    32 - Math.log(end_addr - begin_addr + 1, 2).to_i
  end

  def to_cidr_s
    to_s + "/#{prefix}"
  end
end
```

Parts of the snipped above are taken from `IPAddr#to_range`.

Comment: Despite surface indications, this does not appear to work for IPv6 CIDRs: `IPAddr.new('2001:db8::/113').to_cidr_s #=> "2001:db8::/17"`. The answer above does, however.